# I am creating an Node.js app and I need to install ejs but I am unable to install it. It is showing me the following error

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs

```
node --harmony ./postinstall.js
```

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> npm WARN @react-navigation/core@3.7.5 requires a peer of react@* but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-native-safe-area-view@0.14.9 requires a peer of react@*
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-native-safe-area-view@0.14.9 requires a peer of
>   react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-navigation@4.3.7 requires a peer of react@* but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-navigation@4.3.7 requires a peer of react-native@* but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN ashutosh@1.0.0 No description
>
> npm WARN ashutosh@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! ejs@3.1.3 postinstall: `node --harmony ./postinstall.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the ejs@3.1.3 postinstall script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-22T23_26_50_117Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a path to NodeJS inside your [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) list.

On some OS reboot might be needed to make this work.
Try reboot or reinstall NodeJS and then reboot.